# How to clear browser cache or cookies when user logout?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, windows-authentication, ssom

I have custom **signout.aspx** page which is auto redirected when user session timeout expired. 
Problem is when user clicks the Back arrow or opens same site again, there is no prompt for authentication means user is still in login mode.

Importantly I am using **Windows authentication** and **SSOM**.

My problem is to clear the cache or cookies whatever so that user should be prompted for login again.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are outside the realm of SharePoint now and into straight web development.  Basically calling Session.Abandon() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310.aspx) in your onLoad should do this for you.

You might need to delete cookies, but I think the Abandon call kills everything in the session enough. A new one needs to be created thus requiring you to login again.

Comment: Thaks for your reply David but I am still not able to achieve this. I have found a workaround closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true, which works perfectly for all browsers except IE10, Safari.